# Disable Dynamism Tablet from Thaumic Tinkerer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm making a Minecraft modpack, enabling and disabling items and such (you know the drill). I was wondering how would I disable the Dynamism Tablet from Thaumic Tinkerer, I think the item isn't necessarily a good fit in my pack.

I already have Minetweaker/Modtweaker, but I read on the Wiki that Modtweaker support for Thaumic Tinkerer hasn't come yet.

Does anyone know what I can do for this problem? Or maybe also what to do for problems like this in the future?